# Google maps add listener to marker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add event listener to all markers, i'm using Google-Maps-for-Rails gem. This is my code

```
  markers_from_api = data.bookings
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google')
  settings = {
    internal: {
      id: 'multi_markers'
    },
    provider:{
      styles: mapStyles
    }
  }
  handler.buildMap settings, ->
    markers = handler.addMarkers(markers_from_api)
    _.each markers,(i, j) ->
      google.maps.event.addListener i, 'click', (object) ->
        alert 'hello'
        return
    createSidebar markers_from_api
    createSidebarLi markers_from_api
    handler.bounds.extendWith markers
    handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

I tried to add event listener to all marker but it doesnt alert anything. How can i add event listeners in google maps for rails

I have an array of data, where each data contain id, lat, lng

Comment: You can try to check this [documentation](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-google-maps-rails/) about Google Maps with Rails. It covers in this documentation on how to add event listener in the marker. So just check the example code on how to properly implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  markers_from_api = data.bookings
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google')
  settings = {
    internal: {
      id: 'multi_markers'
    },
    provider:{
      styles: mapStyles
    }
  }
  handler.buildMap settings, ->
    markers = handler.addMarkers(markers_from_api)
    _.each markers,(marker, j) ->
      google.maps.event.addListener marker.serviceObject, 'click', (object) ->
        console.log marker.serviceObject.position.lng()
        render_marker_data markers_from_api[j].id
        return
    handler.bounds.extendWith markers
    handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

the above code marker.serviceObject actually able to get the click event on the marker.